# Activity Buttons still ACTIVE when replaced by Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically, I want to open a `fragment` from `Activity`. Everything worked fine (activity button opens the fragment and the fragment shows), until I miss-clicked outside the `fragment's` layout where one of the `Activity` button is located and it did its `onClick` method. That's why I wondered why is my `Activity` still active.

this is how I open the `fragment` from `Activity`

I tried using `.add` instead of `.replace` still the same.

```
@OnClick(R.id.login_register_lbl)
public void registerAction(View view) {
    // TODO register transition...

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = (LoginActivity.this.getFragmentManager());
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    RegisterFragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_register_holder, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: set android:clickable="true" and android:focusable="true" on your parent layout of fragment xml file

Comment: @HimeshGoswami thanks man! just as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fragment layout in root element set "background" , "clickable=true" & Focusable="true".

Comment: If your fragment layout do not cover whole activity then, if you click outside fragment then activity components would get clicked. Can you please share some screenshot of activity with and without fragment?

Comment: my fragment covers the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can achieve this functionality by 2 ways:

1. Open a dialog fragment in full screen mode to avoid accidentally clicks on activities views.
2. If you wanted to show both fragment's and activity's views at the same time then, on click of your activity's button which opens the fragment, disable it by `yourbutton.setenabled(false);` and when you wanted to close the fragment enable that button again.

Comment: my fragment covers the whole page.

Comment: share screenshot